# Probability of random variable from group A being larger than group B

Tags: r, probability

I have two datasets that contain people's height (among other details) stored in data frames:

```
dataset1$height
dataset2$height
```

I need to know the probability of a randomly selected height from dataset1 will be larger than a randomly selected height from dataset2.

I'm aware I'm trying to calculate `P(X-Y)>0` here, but I'm not sure how to put this in R, and how to get an answer for P (i.e. what is the probability that `dataset1$height - dataset2$height > 0`).

I've calculated the mean, variance and standard deviation for the height in each dataset, I'm just not sure how to fit these calculations into a formula that results in the probability.

For reproducibility, the following samples could represent the what I have:

```
dataset1 = rnorm(100, mean = 11, sd = 2)
dataset2 = rnorm(100, mean = 10, sd = 2)
mean1 = mean(dataset1)
mean2 = mean(dataset2)
var1 = var(dataset1)
var2 = var(dataset2)
sdev1 = sd(dataset1)
sdev2 = sd(dataset2)
Probability = mean(dataset2)/mean(dataset1)
Probability
```

Comment: Are you looking for function [`t.test`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/t.test.html) with `alternative = "greater"`?

Comment: If you don't need an exact value, try a monte carlo simulation: `{N <- 20000000; sum(sample(dataset1, N, TRUE) > sample(dataset2, N, TRUE))/N}`  For an exact formula, look at: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50501/probability-of-one-random-variable-being-greater-than-another

Comment: Here's an exact answer, though probably not what you're looking for: `{M <- outer(dataset1, dataset2, ">"); sum(M) / length(M)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the way you phrased your question, `dataset1` and `dataset2` are the considered the populations from which your RV is drawn. In that case, Montgomery is correct that you could average all pairwise comparisons between `dataset1` and `dataset2`:

```
mean(outer(dataset1, dataset2, ">"))
```

Although, a more efficient method for larger datasets would be to use the ordering of the concatenated vectors:

```
d12 <- order(c(dataset1, dataset2))
sum(cumsum(d12 > length(dataset1))[d12 <= length(dataset1)])/length(dataset1)/length(dataset2)
```

If, on the other hand, `dataset1` and `dataset2` represent samples from parent distributions, and you want to know the probability that a randomly selected height from X ~ distribution1 will be larger than a randomly selected height from Y ~ distribution2, it would depend on your knowledge/assumptions about the underlying distributions. For example, if they were both independent normal distributions with known means `mu1`, `mu2` and standard deviations `sigma1`, `sigma2`, then the distribution of X - Y would be normal with mean `mu1 - mu2` and standard deviation `sqrt(sigma1^2 + sigma2^2)`. P(X > Y) would be:

```
pnorm(0, mean = mu1 - mu2, sd = sqrt(sigma1^2 + sigma2^2), lower.tail = FALSE)
```

Using larger vectors with your example parameters, the two approaches give similar answers:

```
> set.seed(94)
> mu1 <- 11; mu2 <- 10; sigma1 <- 2; sigma2 <- 2
> dataset1 = rnorm(1e6, mean = mu1, sd = sigma1)
> dataset2 = rnorm(1e6, mean = mu2, sd = sigma2)
> d12 <- order(c(dataset1, dataset2)); sum(cumsum(d12 > length(dataset1))[d12 <= length(dataset1)])/length(dataset1)/length(dataset2)
[1] 0.6384645
> pnorm(0, mean = mu1 - mu2, sd = sqrt(sigma1^2 + sigma2^2), lower.tail = FALSE)
[1] 0.6381632
```

Answer (score 0):

We can make use of the fact that Pr(X>Y) = 1-E[F_X(Y)] to create an efficient function for computing the probability. Note that the other answers using `outer()` are going to blow up memory usage because they create a huge Nx by Ny matrix. This will be slow.

```
# sample some data, but with discrete values 
# just to check that it works
set.seed(1)

# Make Ns big to see slowdown
dataset1 = rbinom(100000, 10, .2)
dataset2 = rbinom(5000, 10, .3)

system.time({
  Fx = ecdf(dataset1)
  Pr1 = 1-mean(Fx(dataset2))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#      0       0       0  
Pr1
# [1] 0.2174595

system.time({
  Pr2 = mean(outer(dataset1, dataset2, ">"))
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.19    0.28    2.47 
 
Pr2
# [1] 0.2174595
```

If you profiled the memory usage, you'd also see the `outer` method uses much more memory.

Comment: `ecdf` makes it nicely concise. A one liner:
`mean(ecdf(dataset2)(dataset1))`

Comment: You do have to be careful with discrete values where Pr(x<=y) =/= Pr(y>x) (ECDF computes Pr(x<=y)).